# How to fix error override CSS when change component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-loader

## Login.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Login extends React.Component {
   componentWillMount(){
        import ('./styles/login_page.css');
    }
   ....
   <Link to="/register">Create account</Link>
}
```

## Register.js

```
import React from 'react''

export default class Register extends React.Component {
   componentWillMount(){
        import ('./styles/register_page.css');
    }
   ....
   <Link to="/login">Login Now</Link>
}
```

## App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './Login'
import Register from './Register'
import PageNotFound from './PageNotFound'

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login }/>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/register' component={Register }/>
        <Route component={PageNotFound} />
      </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

After rendering, I click Login then click Create account and click again Login, login component's CSS is overrided by register component's CSS and home page is same. I want when going to any component, component's CSS is loading. Is there way to fix?

Comment: what is common between both css?

Comment: Please refer this, it helps you to solve this issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714752/how-to-import-css-for-only-any-component-in-reactjs/57714960#57714960

Comment: I have refered but CSS is loaded, they will overwrite the before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically resolved by using [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) in CSS. You need to set a distinct class in the root element of each component, and declare all other CSS styles by writing their selectors as descendants of that class.

Login.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Login extends React.Component {
   componentWillMount(){
        import ('./styles/login_page.css');
    }
   ....
   <Link class="login-component" to="/register">Create account</Link>
}
```

login_page.css

```
.login-component .item1 { ... }
.login-component .item2 { ... }
```

Register.js

```
import React from 'react''

export default class Register extends React.Component {
   componentWillMount(){
        import ('./styles/register_page.css');
    }
   ....
   <Link class="register-component" to="/login">Login Now</Link>
}
```

register_page.css

```
.register-component .item1 { ... }
.register-component .item2 { ... }
```

So even if both components have elements matching `.item1` and `.item2`, they will select the correct rule due to the descendant combinator. This might be a bit verbose with raw CSS, but if you're using any preprocessor it should be pretty simple.

Else, you might just want to make the selectors distinct somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same challenge while using different css modules within the same app, I guess the problem is while the compiler is building the css, since all the css are compiled into a single file you might want differentiate them by giving them diffrent main class name.

**The solution in that case is to nest your css styles in the base class if your using sass**

```
.loginpageContainer {
  .input{ //custom css
 }}
.registerPageContainer{ 
 .input{
// custom css
}}
```

**Same wise if your using pure css just use the main class**

```
.loginContainer .login .input{
//custom css
} 
.registerContainer .login .input{
//custom css
}
```